# MS Access 2016 crashes on a certain linked SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2016

I imported MS Access tables into a SQL Server 2012 database. In MS Access, when I change the link to the SQL Server table, the database does not open (stops responding and closes).

I change them back to the Access tables and they open fine. I then change the links one table at a time and re-open. It isn't until I get to one table (that only has an `int Identity` and a `nvarchar(20)` column) that it stops opening.

What is going on? When it is linked to the SQL Server table (and I open the MS Access database using the shift key) I am able to open the table and add/edit records. It seems to just not like opening the initial form that uses this table.

I even deleted the SQL Server table and built it from scratch and it still crashes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

1. It is important for us to know what's going on when you don't prevent execution by pressing the shift key.
   Please show us the code being executed.
2. In general, it is always worth a try to decompile/compact the database in case of strange behavior: `"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "c:\test\YourDatabase.accdb" /decompile /compact`

   Remark: The path to the exe depends on the Access version/platform you installed.
   So for Access 2016 it could be one of these (64bit/32bit):

   - `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE`
   - `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE`
3. In addition, in such strange situations, it is also worth making sure that Microsoft Access is fully patched. The search and installation of updates should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

what is the name of the table? (access and sql have different reserved words) and if you use one of them, you may be able to create a table but never access it.
If the table name has spaces in it, Access is generally ok, but sql is really not ok.

Simple solution: If you have spaces in the name - remove them and relink.
As most reserved words are single words - if you use a single word as the table name, change it to two words joined together.